# Oppo Phone removing Device Admin Permission

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, device-admin, oppo

In my application I am using Device admin permission, It is working fine in all devices but In Latest Oppo Phones F9, F7, F5 whenever user unlocks phone it askes to remove Admin permission Or Shows a dialogue to remove admin permissions of all applications,

My App is not working without admin permissions,

I am stuck here, looking for a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have found that, this is device issue, Oppo has added this security purpose

In this case for oppo f7 user has to ignore popup of permission.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not own an Oppo phone, though my older Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 had similar issues so this should be it.

Go to Settings/Security Center on your Oppo phone and disable "Permission Monitor." This should be what is causing the popups.

[Source:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT0D5J2Ji4A) Credit to Ameer Hamza Khan.

Answer (score 0):

**oppof19Pro**> Create a blockquote by

> prepending “>” to each line.
>
> Other formatting also works here, e.g.
>
> 1. Lists or
> 2. Headings:
>
> ### Quoted Heading

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).